# How to print prime numbers within given range | Oracle 19c |

Tags: sql, oracle, primes

I have been trying to write a **logic** to **print all prime numbers**.

And it works as expected till **range of** `1` to `100`.

But when I increase the range it **dose not work** from `1` to `500`

Can some explain in details what is wrong in my below code and how it can be improved.

Any easy or different way to **print prime numbers** will be much appreciated

**Code :**

```
SELECT
    result
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN ROWNUM = 2 THEN
                    ROWNUM
                WHEN ROWNUM = 3 THEN
                    ROWNUM
                WHEN ROWNUM = 5 THEN
                    ROWNUM
            END AS result
        FROM
            dual
        CONNECT BY
            ROWNUM <= 5
    )
WHERE
    result IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
    result
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            decr1 AS result
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    rn AS decr1
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT
                            ROWNUM AS rn
                        FROM
                            dual
                        CONNECT BY
                            ROWNUM < 1000
                    )
            )
        WHERE
            decr1 > 5
        MINUS
        SELECT
            decr AS result
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    t.rn AS decr
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT
                            ROWNUM AS rn
                        FROM
                            dual
                        CONNECT BY
                            ROWNUM < 1000
                    ) t
                WHERE
                    rn >= 6
            )
        WHERE
            mod(decr, 2) = 0
            OR mod(decr, 3) = 0
            OR mod(decr, 4) = 0
            OR mod(decr, 5) = 0
            OR mod(decr, 6) = 0
            OR mod(decr, 7) = 0
            OR mod(decr, 8) = 0
            OR mod(decr, 9) = 0
            OR mod(decr, 10) = 0
    );
```

**My output for range of** `1` to `100`

[image: output]

Comment: "it does not work" isn't very helpful - do you get an error, or wrong results, or something else?

Comment: @AlexPoole : Please find my output attached it worked till 100 and generated output. And when range is increased it got failed to give prime numbers

Comment: "it failed" also isn't very helpful. Please edit your question to include the full error message you got, or the wrong results if there wasn't an error.

Comment: You do realize that even your current query doesn't give the correct result, right? The prime number 7 is missing from your output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've thrown out processing efficiency when you decided to do this in SQL, so you might as well go for something that is clear.  Here is a SQL that is pretty much straight along the lines of the definition of a prime number:

```
with nat as (SELECT rownum n FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 100 )
SELECT n   -- give me any number...
from   nat n1  -- ... from the set of natural numbers ...
where   not exists ( SELECT n FROM nat n2 where mod(n1.n,n2.n)=0 AND n2.n between 2 and n1.n-1)  -- ... that cannot be evenly divided by a smaller natural number
and n > 1  -- ... and 1 is not prime
```

Comment: Can you explain the approach how your query works

Comment: No need to make it so inefficient. Certainly check divisors only up to sqrt(n1.n), not up to n1.n - 1. That is not a big change, and it will cut down significantly on the number of computations required.

Comment: Instead of `SQRT(n1.n)` as you could use `n2.n*n2.n BETWEEN 4 AND n1.n` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HcVeenPj)

Comment: Those are all good improvements.  The point wasn't really to optimize since it's only 1..100 and SQL is the wrong choice if you care about fast.  I didn't want to give the impression that this was a good or optimized way to find prime numbers, since it's not really.  It's just short and readable (imo).

Answer (score 5):

A positive integer is prime if it is strictly greater than 1, and if it is not divisible by any positive integers besides 1 and the number itself. To check for primality, it is enough to know if the number is divisible by a number between 2 and trunc(sqrt(that_number)). In code:

```
with
  user_input (n) as (
    select :n              -- user input goes here
    from   dual
  )
, candidates (p) as (
    select  level
    from    user_input 
    where   level > 1
    connect by level <= n
  )
, prep (f) as (
    select  level
    from    dual
    where   level > 1
    connect by level <= trunc(sqrt(:n))
  )
select p as prime
from   candidates
where  not exists (
                    select f
                    from   prep
                    where  f <= trunc(sqrt(p))
                           and
                           mod(p, f) = 0
                  )
;
```

The input (at the top of the query, in the `with` clause) is a bind variable, you can set it to 100 or whatever you need.

NOTE: This will be quite slow if you need all the primes up to 100,000 for example (it takes 2.3 seconds on my machine). Don't even try up to 1 million or more. For those, you need a better algorithm. We all learned the Erathostenes' sieve algorithm in primary school; that is trivial to code in a procedural language (like PL/SQL), not so easy in a declarative language (like SQL - proving that "declarative" is just a marketing word, and perhaps an ideal, but not a reality). For a pretty long discussion see https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/3931268/sql-puzzle-prime-numbers/p1
which was rendered hard to read by Oracle's change of forum platform provider a few years back.

Comment: Don't know if primality is a word or not, but if it isn't it should be! Great answer.

Comment: @Andrew - it is.

Answer (score 2):

```
select num prime_number
from (select level num from dual connect by level <= 500 ),
 (select level denom from dual connect by level <= 500 )
where denom<=num
group by num
having count(case num/denom when trunc(num/denom) then 'Y' end) = 2
order by num
```

Using Oracle's connect, we can generate our set of numerators and denominators. Then we can filter any denominators greater than the numerator (no point in dividing 2 by 3, etc). Finally, the having clause will return the prime numbers.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/a8Dxj1tI)
The first query in the fiddle kind of shows what is going on, the second one is gives you your primes.

Answer (score 2):

Adjust the CONNECT by value if you want more or less values

```
select a output
    from (select level a from dual connect by level <= 500),
         (select level b from dual connect by level <= 500)
    where b<=a
    group by a
    having count(case a/b when trunc(a/b) then 'Y' end) = 2
    order by a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use use a row-generator to generate all the values and then use `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` to check if each value is prime:

```sql
SELECT prime
FROM   (
         SELECT LEVEL + 1 AS prime
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL < 100
       ) p
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   DUAL
         WHERE  MOD(prime, level) = 0
         CONNECT BY LEVEL * LEVEL <= prime
         HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
       )
```

Which outputs:

> | PRIME |
> | --- |
> | 2 |
> | 3 |
> | 5 |
> | 7 |
> | 11 |
> | 13 |
> | 17 |
> | 19 |
> | 23 |
> | 29 |
> | 31 |
> | 37 |
> | 41 |
> | 43 |
> | 47 |
> | 53 |
> | 59 |
> | 61 |
> | 67 |
> | 71 |
> | 73 |
> | 79 |
> | 83 |
> | 89 |
> | 97 |

*[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/791QJz50)*

Answer (score 0):

Hooray finally !!!

I was able to solve the question by taking references from all @authors

My sincere thank you to all the author who as come up with **different solution**

I got few ideas from your logic which help me to write a below query

**My code :**

```
with input(val) as
(
        SELECT
            :val
        FROM
            dual
)
,
auto_generate_number_sequence as
(
        SELECT
            numbr
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    6 * level - 1 AS numbr
                FROM
                    dual
                CONNECT BY
                    level < :val
                UNION
                SELECT
                    6 * level + 1 AS numbr
                FROM
                    dual 
                CONNECT BY
                    level < :val 
            )
        WHERE
            numbr <= :val
) , 
generate_sqrt_of_input as 
(
            select 
                level as sqrtnum 
                   from dual where  level > 1 connect by level <=sqrt(:val)  
)
, get_numbers_remainder_zero as 
(
        SELECT
            numbr,
            mod(numbr, sqrtnum) AS md
        FROM
                 auto_generate_number_sequence
            CROSS JOIN generate_sqrt_of_input
        WHERE
                sqrtnum < (numbr/2)
            AND mod(numbr, sqrtnum) = 0
        ORDER BY
            numbr,
            mod(numbr, sqrtnum)
)
SELECT
            level numbr
        FROM
            dual where level > 1 
        CONNECT BY
            level <=3
UNION
SELECT
    numbr
FROM
    auto_generate_number_sequence
MINUS
SELECT
    numbr
FROM
    get_numbers_remainder_zero;
```

**Please feel free to correct me If any issue with my above query**